# @TableGenerator not working with EclipseLink JPA 2.0

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I am having a weird issue.
i am using Table Generation strategy in my JPA application. until recently, I used Toplink persistence provider as the JPA implementation. All worked fine.
Just now I added some inheritance features that are not supported by TopLink (Table per Class Inheritance), so I had to move to EclipseLink.
All works fine, except for the ID Generation.
Here is the code example which I use for all my unique IDs:

```
@Id
@TableGenerator(name="INCOME_SEQ", table="SEQUENCE_TABLE", pkColumnName="SEQUENCE_NAME",
    valueColumnName="SEQUENCE_COUNT", pkColumnValue="INCOME_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="INCOME_SEQ")
@Column(name = "INCOME_ID")
private Integer incomeId;
```

The exact same code works with Toplink but does not work with EclipseLink.
The Error I get is:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'INCOME_ID' cannot be null
Error Code: 1048
```

It seems like the Table generation is not used at all...

Here is the Table Description in my MySql database:
Table name: SEQUENCE_TABLE

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| SEQUENCE_NAME  | varchar(64)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| SEQUENCE_COUNT | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| localized_name | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| USER_ID        | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | 1       |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Can anyone please direct me to the problem?? or at least a way to get the actual reason the ID is not being created?

Edit: This is the Income class and Table structure:

```
    +-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                   | Type                                                                          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| INCOME_ID               | int(11)                                                                       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| REFERENCE_DOCUMENT_ID   | varchar(32)                                                                   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CLIENT_ID               | int(9)                                                                        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| income_date             | datetime                                                                      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| MOVEMENT_CATEGORY_ID    | int(11)                                                                       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| SUM_AFTER_TAX           | decimal(10,2)                                                                 | YES  |     | 0.00    |       |
| TOTAL_SUM               | decimal(10,2)                                                                 | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| TAX_SUM                 | decimal(10,2)                                                                 | NO   |     | 0.00    |       |
| VAT_PERCENT             | decimal(10,2)                                                                 | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| DESCRIPTION             | varchar(100)                                                                  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| STATUS                  | smallint(5) unsigned                                                          | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| REFERENCE_DOCUMENT_TYPE | enum('MANUAL_INVOICE','MANUAL_RECEIPT','INVOICE','RECEIPT','INVOICE_RECEIPT') | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| USER_ID                 | int(11)                                                                       | NO   | MUL | 1       |       |
| UNIQUE_USER_SEQUENCE    | int(10) unsigned                                                              | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Edit: I ran the app with EclipseLink Logging level set to finest, but I still can't see anything wrong. I even can see the sequencing being correctly initialized:

```
  [EL Finest]: 2012-11-07 20:37:00.359--ServerSession(1832413009)--Connection(1484802679)--Thread(Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [default].
[EL Finest]: 2012-11-07 20:37:00.405--ServerSession(1832413009)--Thread(Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main])--sequencing connected, state is NoPreallocation_State
[EL Finest]: 2012-11-07 20:37:00.406--ServerSession(1832413009)--Thread(Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main])--sequence SEQ_GEN_IDENTITY: preallocation size 1
[EL Finest]: 2012-11-07 20:37:00.406--ServerSession(1832413009)--Thread(Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main])--sequencing connected, state is Preallocation_Transaction_NoAccessor_State
[EL Finest]: 2012-11-07 20:37:00.406--ServerSession(1832413009)--Thread(Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main])--sequence RECEIPTS_SEQ: preallocation size 1
[EL Finest]: 2012-11-07 20:37:00.406--ServerSession(1832413009)--Thread(Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main])--sequence INCOME_SEQ: preallocation size 1

    [EL Finest]: 2012-11-07 20:38:09.264--UnitOfWork(514772947)--Thread(Thread[AWT-EventQueue-1,6,main])--persist() operation called on:  555 וובה.
[EL Finer]: 2012-11-07 20:38:09.265--UnitOfWork(514772947)--Thread(Thread[AWT-EventQueue-1,6,main])--begin unit of work commit
[EL Finest]: 2012-11-07 20:38:09.288--UnitOfWork(514772947)--Thread(Thread[AWT-EventQueue-1,6,main])--Execute query DoesExistQuery(referenceClass=MovementCategories )
[EL Finest]: 2012-11-07 20:38:09.29--UnitOfWork(514772947)--Thread(Thread[AWT-EventQueue-1,6,main])--Execute query InsertObjectQuery(חש' ידנית 555 וובה)
[EL Finest]: 2012-11-07 20:38:09.291--ServerSession(1832413009)--Connection(1484802679)--Thread(Thread[AWT-EventQueue-1,6,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
[EL Finer]: 2012-11-07 20:38:09.291--ClientSession(2117615354)--Connection(1484802679)--Thread(Thread[AWT-EventQueue-1,6,main])--begin transaction
[EL Fine]: 2012-11-07 20:38:09.293--ClientSession(2117615354)--Connection(1484802679)--Thread(Thread[AWT-EventQueue-1,6,main])--INSERT INTO income (INCOME_ID, DESCRIPTION, INCOME_DATE, REFERENCE_DOCUMENT_ID, REFERENCE_DOCUMENT_TYPE, STATUS, SUM_AFTER_TAX, TAX_SUM, TOTAL_SUM, UNIQUE_USER_SEQUENCE, VAT_PERCENT, CLIENT_ID, MOVEMENT_CATEGORY_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [null, null, 2012-11-07 20:37:55.225, 555, MANUAL_INVOICE, 1, 100.0, 16.5, 116.5, null, 16.5, 334, 3]
```

The only clue I see is the  `Preallocation_Transaction_NoAccessor_State` property...
Maybe someone can help me understand this. What should be the logging output in case of sequenced primary key ID?

Comment: Eclipselink logging is described here http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging try the finest level.

Comment: OK, I got the logging output (thanks for that link...).
I've added the results in the main question

Comment: It doesn't seem like the id is using sequencing, include the full class mappings for Income, also check if you have an orm.xml overriding the annotations, and ensure you are correctly compiling and deploying your code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the log for errors and what SQL is failing.

In your table def, you have a couple other columns?

USER_ID is not something you told JPA about, and is not-null, so I would assume could cause a failure.

If still having issues, include a lot more details.

Comment: The error snippet  I included shows that the SQL Error is telling that the primary key column which is income_id is NULL when inserting the data. the user_id column has a default of '1' so not defining it is not a problem, it simply defaults to '1'. I should mention that the exact same code (with the exact same DB) worked perfectly when I used Toplink as the JPA Provider.
As for more loggging - do you know How I can extract a more detailed log of EclipseLink?

Answer (score 0):

Found The Solution, hope it will be useful for some more people:
For some reason I had the following persistence config setting set for my persistence unit:

```
persistenceMap.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.ID_VALIDATION,"NONE");
```

Apparently turning off ID validation in EclipseLink also turns off ID Generation.

Thanks to all who tried to help!