# EclipseLink and TableGenerator - Id not generated

Tags: java, ejb, eclipselink

I'm working on a JAVAEE Enterprise application, which has the technology stack: Glassfish 3.1, EJB 3.1, EclipseLink 2.4.2, SQL Server 2008 R2. In the EJB module, I have a couple of entities which use SequenceGenerator's and a couple of entities with TableGenerator's.

The SequenceGenerator's are working fine, but the TableGenerator's aren't. I tried to check the server.log by setting the EclipseLink's logging to '**FINEST**', but I don't see any queries logged for getting the next value of the Id. The EJB entity that uses TableGenerator is as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST")
@TableGenerator(name = "test_gen", table = "ID_GENERATOR", pkColumnName = "ID_NAME", pkColumnValue = "TEST", valueColumnName = "ID_VAL", allocationSize = 50, initialValue = 1)
public class Test extends SuperClass implements Interface1, Interface2, Interface3, Interface4, Interface5, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5084413459400887388L;

    /** The id of the entry.
     */
    protected long id = 0;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "test_gen")
    @Column(name = "NWTID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Override
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    .....

}
```

**Note**: The Table 'ID_GENERATOR' is used by all entities with TableGenerator annotation, with a Unique Generator name.

After checking the logs with '**FINEST**' setting, I tried many other ways, but couldn't get the 'TableGenerator' working. Later, I downloaded the EclipseLink's (2.4.2) sources and debugged the 'Sequencing' mechanism, during deployment, as well as at application runtime. During deployment, I found the Sequence 'TEST' to be initialized, but at runtime, the Id's are not being generated.

BTW, my persistence.xml has a couple of datasources, with the following properties for EclipseLink:

```
<persistence-unit name="TestCtx" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>TESTDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database"  value="SQLServer"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>            
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.id-validation" value="NULL"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="NONE"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="false"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.session" value="false"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.timestamp" value="false"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.exceptions" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Do you have any clue, as to what's happening here?

Comment: Did a sequence table get created, and if so, is there a row for test?  How are you persisting your entities and what value is used for the insert?  You might want to specify a non-JTA datasource so it can be used outside the transaction for sequencing

Comment: As mentioned in my original post, we are using "table = "ID_GENERATOR"" to store the sequencing information. So, SEQUENCE table is not generated and not used, but I tried that option too.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear - was the sequence table "ID_GENERATOR" created, and if so, is there a row for "TEST" in it?  Try clearing the schema and see what gets created with the DDL generation.

Comment: Chris:  All that check has been done. The table exists and the row with TEST data exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. The culprit is the Eclipse-Link property 'eclipselink.id-validation', defined in the persistence.xml file:

```
<property name="eclipselink.id-validation" value="NULL"/>
```

Actually, I knew about this already, that defining this property would stop ID/Sequence generation, [as discussed in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222677/tablegenerator-not-working-with-eclipselink-jpa-2-0). But, I thought that this applies, only when the property is set to 'NONE'. In my case, it is set to 'NULL'. Also, SequenceGenerator's are working fine, even when this property is set. So, logically, I thought the TableGenerator's (which use TableSequence - as per EclipseLink's source code) should work, when the property is set to 'NULL'. So, removing this property worked for me.

Also, note that the below property has the same effect on TableGenerator's (Id/Sequence is not generated):

```
<property name="eclipselink.allow-zero-id" value="true"/>
```